# How to get rid of black line above UITabBar when changing color of tab bar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I have a code that changes a tab bar color like this

```
    UITabBar *tabBar = [vc.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
    CGRect rectAdjust = CGRectMake(roundf(screenWidth - 305.0f) / 2.0f, screenHeight - 54.0f - 10.0f,  305.0f, 54.0f);
    tabBar.frame = rectAdjust;

    UIColor *tabbarBg = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9 green:0.9 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0];
    tabBar.tintColor = tabbarBg;
```

The code should change color of tab bar without any flaw however, I got this result

[image]

notice that there has a black line above my tab bar. I don't know where this comes from.

How to get rid of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove black line on top of the `UITabBar` then use  following suggestion,

Add following framework in your project

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

And write following code

```
self.tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.50;
self.tabBar.layer.borderColor = self.tabBar.tintColor.CGColor;
```

**Edited**

I did not tried but I think **@Nav's** comment should be work if not then use above suggestion.

Comment: @Sizer - i dont know but this same types of issue came with me and i solved by above code :) thanks :)

Comment: I have also noticed that self.tabBar.clipsToBounds = YES; also hides the black like on top of the tab bar

Comment: its  appear on the border  of tabbar, but i want only on the top not on the left , right and bottom.